# Load XML file into a Datatable

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datatable

I am trying to load an xml file into a datable but I don't know where to start. The Xml file has tags to help identify the Headers, the rows, and the columns. Below is a sample:

```
<result>
  <info>
    <title>Summary By Employee: My Default</title>
    <sorted-by>Employee Name Ascending</sorted-by>
    <filtered-by>Employee: All; Dates: 01/11/2015-01/17/2015</filtered-by>
    <date>01/21/2015</date>
    <time>08:40a</time>
    <generated-by>Joe Doe </generated-by>
  </info>
<header>
<col>
  <label>Employee Id</label>
</col>
<col>
  <label>Employee Name</label>
</col>
<col>
  <label>Regular</label>
</col>
<col>
  <label>Overtime</label>
</col>
<col>
  <label>Premium</label>
</col>
<col>
</header>
<body>
<row>
  <col>022692</col>
  <col>James, Mitchel</col>
  <col>-</col>
  <col>-</col>
  <col>-</col>
</row>
<row>
  <col>022685</col>
  <col>Doe, Joe</col>
  <col>-</col>
  <col>-</col>
  <col>-</col>
</row>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Start by checking the documentation of the DataTable and DataSet classes for any methods called LoadXXX. Or google it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. You would need to use **System.Xml.Linq**.

```
           string xml = @"<result>
                              <info>
                                <title>Summary By Employee: My Default</title>
                                <sorted-by>Employee Name Ascending</sorted-by>
                                <filtered-by>Employee: All; Dates: 01/11/2015-01/17/2015</filtered-by>
                                <date>01/21/2015</date>
                                <time>08:40a</time>
                                <generated-by>Joe Doe </generated-by>
                              </info>
                            <header>
                            <col>
                              <label>Employee Id</label>
                            </col>
                            <col>
                              <label>Employee Name</label>
                            </col>
                            <col>
                              <label>Regular</label>
                            </col>
                            <col>
                              <label>Overtime</label>
                            </col>
                            <col>
                              <label>Premium</label>
                            </col> 
                            </header>
                            <body>
                            <row>
                              <col>022692</col>
                              <col>James, Mitchel</col>
                              <col>-</col>
                              <col>-</col>
                              <col>-</col>
                            </row>
                            <row>
                              <col>022685</col>
                              <col>Doe, Joe</col>
                              <col>-</col>
                              <col>-</col>
                              <col>-</col>
                            </row></body></result>";

        StringReader xmlReader= new StringReader(xml);
        DataSet ds= new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);

        DataTable result = ds.Tables[0];
```

The above would produce the following dataset...
[image]

Comment: You are almost right. I apologize, I must not have explained myself very well. The headers should be the employeeID, EmployeeName, Regular, Overtime,Premium. What is inside the <info> tags is irrelevant.

Comment: In that case you'd just need to update your XML source.... That's all - but to load XML data into a datatable/dataset use the above code.